# React get Ref of active element to get getBoundingClientRect().x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getboundingclientrect

Hello I have a question about how to get the Ref of a React element (named **spanNav2**) from the active element. The example below works perfectly. I am able to get the **x** value using **getBoundingClientRect().x** and move the span element (see below). The only problem is that **spanNav2** is fixed. I just want to be able to get the number **2** and replace it with the injected number (value) as I am doing in the **navigate** element.

```
    onButtonClick = value => {
      const open = !this.state.open;
      const navigate = `cd-marker color-${value}`;
      const activeElement = `${this.spanNav2.getBoundingClientRect().x}`;

      const newState = {
        open,
        navigate,
        activeElement
      };

      this.setState(newState);

      if (open) {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ animate: false }), 200);
      }
    };
```

Inside the render element I have:

```
<li ref={input => {this.spanNav4 = input;}}>
<NavLinkPage2 onClick={value => this.onButtonClick(2)}>Content</NavLinkPage2</li>
```

And at the bottom of the page I have a styled span element that I want to move to the left to sit below the active element (NavLink from React Router)

```
<span className={this.state.navigate} style={{ left: `${this.state.activeElement}px` }} />
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `value` is a number, then you could do something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.refs = {}

onButtonClick = value => {
  const open = !this.state.open;
  const navigate = `cd-marker color-${value}`;
  const activeElement = `${this.refs[value].getBoundingClientRect().x}`;
```

And inside the `render` function, assuming again you `map` over some collection of items:

```
render() {
    return (
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
            <li ref={input => {this.refs[index] = input}}>
            <NavLinkPage2 onClick={value => 
              this.onButtonClick(index)}>{item}</NavLinkPage2>
            </li>
        )}
    )    
}
```

Comment: Hello @thedude I am not mapping a collection of items. I just have 5 items that are somehow unique components in them. Each item has it's own Ref and using getBoundingClientRect().x I can get all 5 of the x values I am after. I just want to inject into the onButtonClick the 1 ref of the active value. Thank you for your reply. Will try to restructure the code a bit and see if I can map my elements somehow.